# C++ Code that runs immediately when the program is turned on

Tags: c++

```
struct First{
    First(){
        printf("first");
    }
}First;

int main()
{
    print("second");
    return 0;
}
```

I know I can control the code that is executed first through the structure.
So I want to use the following code to make it simple through macro.

```
#define FIRST_INVOKE(NAME,FUNCTION) \
struct NAME  \
{ \
    NAME() \
    { \
        FUNCTION(); \
    } \
} NAME;
namespace Foo
{
    namespace Bar
    {
        void FirstFunction()
        {
            LOGD(LVID, "First");
        }
    }
}
FIRST_INVOKE(UniqueStructName, Foo::Bar::FirstFunction);
```

When creating a macro, you must specify the name of the structure. (UniqueStructName)
I want to set this to a name that does not overlap globally automatically.

Namespace and class static functions cannot be included in structure names because :: is required.

Please let me know if there is a good way (I am using Xcode.)

Comment: If you just want to run some things before main() starts you may be better off looking into platform specific methods such as Windows DllMain's Attach messages. Or the Windows `init_seg` pragma. In ELF systems like Linux there's space for "constructor" functions. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functions-that-are-executed-before-and-after-main-in-c/

Comment: You wi ll need platform specific knowledge anyway if you need to run code in specific order between different source files. You need to control how the linker places and orders the construct functions.

Comment: @ZanLynx Thank you, what you want is a macro that binds to a particular feature in a way that doesn't access the code in the main architecture.

Comment: Why does hardcoded is not allowed? Is there any restriction? I'd like to use macro as less as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automatically generate names based on the line number and use anonymous namespace to avoid multiple definitions across files. E.g, using the following macro:

```
#define CONCAT_(A,B) A##B
#define CONCAT(A,B) CONCAT_(A,B)
#define NONAME() CONCAT(noname_, __LINE__)
#define FIRST_INVOKE(FUNCTION) \
namespace {                          \
    struct NONAME() \
    { \
        NONAME()() \
        { \
            FUNCTION(); \
        } \
    } NONAME();                      \
}
```

This will expand to a `noname_X` struct, where `X` is the line-number. This works as long as you do not repeat the macro on the same line.

Comment: I'm concerned about using the same line in different files, is there a better way?

Comment: @Lim, that's why it is in an anonymous namespace, to avoid issues with same line number in different files